# Tomcat SSL_CLIENT_S_DN Request Header

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I have a webapp running within a Tomcat instance (9.0.31) in which I need specific HTTPS header requests from the HttpServletRequest. However it appears the HttpServletRequest does not have the specific request such as **SSL_CLIENT_S_DN**.

I have enabled **clientAuth="true"** inside the Tomcat server.xml file.

It should be noted that I am **NOT** proxying the request via Apache HTTPD and as such adding the follow to /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf is not possible.

```
RequestHeader set SSL_CLIENT_S_DN "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}s"
```

Answer (score 0):

After a fair amount of research I am unclear if a HeaderRequest **SSL_CLIENT_S_DN** even exists in Tomcat.

For clarification I originally attempted the following

```
  HttpServletRequest request = <HttpServletRequest Object>
  String certDN = request.getHeader("SSL_CLIENT_S_DN");
```

Since **SSL_CLIENT_S_DN** did not exist, this would results in an empty or null string.

Instead I had to make a call to **getAttribute()** to retrieve the certificate information that way.

```
  HttpServletRequest request = <HttpServletRequest Object>
  X509Certificate certs[] = (X509Certificate[])request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")
  for (X509Certificate cert : certs)
  {
      sys.stdout.print("Issuer DN [" + cert.getIssuerDN() + "]");
  }
```